# Clear only single input field angular6 template driven form

Tags: angular

I have a simple template driven form in Angular 6. On form submit I want to clear only 1 field from component file. Is this possible and how. The form field is having #username

Comment: Can you show, what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the input to a variable using `[(ngModel)]`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username">
 <!-- Other inputs -->
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and you will handle on onSubmit() in component

```
onSubmit(){
  this.username = "";
}
```

assuming that you have a variable username declared in component.

Answer (score 0):

for angular 13 I did this;
first import ViewChild from '@angular/core'
then declare it like so:

@ViewChild('ngForm_name')
ngForm_name!: NgForm;

now you can call the form instance and make your changes in any function like so:

```
let inputName = this.ngForm_name.control.get('inputName');
if (inputName?.valid || inputName?.touched) {
  this.ngForm_name.control.patchValue({inputName: undefined || "new value"});
}
```

hope this helps